# How to determine the dependencies of older npm package versions

Tags: npm, upgrade, package.json, npm-scripts

It appears to me that the dependency linkage on the npm site is only applicable to the current/latest version.

Is there some tidbit of information that I'm not aware of on how to determine what dependency version a package has other than by downloading it and inspecting the package.json file?

I feel like I'm wasting HOURS doing something I would expect to be much easier to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *"It appears to me that the dependency linkage on the npm site is only applicable to the current/latest version."*

Yes that's correct, `www.npmjs.com` will *only* show the dependencies for the latest version of a package.

Here are a couple of ways to discover what you want both programmatically and non-programmatically.

#### Programmatically:

1. Utilizing the [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view.html) command with the following syntax;

   ```
   npm view <pkg_name> versions --json
   ```

   obtains a list of all versions available for a given package in the npm registry.

   <sub>**Note:** The `<pkg_name>` part above should be substituted with the real package name.</sub>

   For instance; running the following command for let's say the [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) package:

   ```
   npm view eslint versions --json
   ```

   prints the following to the console:

   > ```
   > [
   >   "0.0.4",
   >   "0.0.5",
   >   "0.0.6",
   >   "0.0.7",
   >   "0.1.0-dev",
   >   "0.1.0",
   >   "0.1.1",
   >   "0.1.2",
   >   ...
   > ]
   > ```
2. Now we know what versions are available, let's say we want to list the *dependencies* for `eslint` version `0.1.2` we can run the following command:

   ```
   npm show eslint@0.1.2 dependencies --json
   ```

   This will print:

   > ```
   > {
   >   "optimist": "*",
   >   "estraverse": "~1.3.0",
   >   "esprima": "*",
   >   "escope": "1.0.0"
   > }
   > ```

   Similarly, we can discover the *devDependencies* for `eslint` version `0.1.2` by running the following command instead:

   ```
   npm show eslint@0.1.2 devDependencies --json
   ```

   This will yield something like this:

   > ```
   > {
   >   "vows": "~0.7.0",
   >   "sinon": "*",
   >   "commonjs-everywhere": "~0.9.0",
   >   "mocha": "~1.13.0",
   >   "chai": "~1.8.1",
   >   "grunt": "~0.4.1",
   >   ...
   > }
   > ```
3. If you know that a package has a particular dependency in advance.

   For instance; retrospectively after running the aforementioned command we now know that `eslint` version `0.1.2` has `escope` listed as a dependency.

   So, if we wanted to know the version of `escope` that `eslint` version `0.1.2` needs, we can run the following command:

   ```
   npm show eslint@0.1.2 dependencies.escope
                                     ^
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** The package name follows the dot (`.`), i.e. `.escope`</sub>

   This prints the following:

   > `1.0.0`

---

#### The non-programmatic way

I can't think of a reason why you would want to perform the following non-programmatic way instead of the aforementioned programmatic way when you have a CLI tool available to you. However, if you prefer manual tasks then here goes...

***Note**: YMMV using the following manual steps as it depends on how the package has been managed/maintained.*

Typically, the source code of an npm package will be hosted on GitHub, so you can perform the following manual steps. This will avoid you having to download the package to inspect the *package.json* file.

For this we'll demonstrate for the `eslint` package:

1. Visit [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) and type the name of the package in the *"Search Packages"* input field. We'll type `eslint` and hit the return key.
2. Next click `eslint` from the list of packages, which will take you to [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint).
3. Click on the *github* link which typically appears on the right-hand side of the webpage and looks like this:

   [image: github rep link icon]
4. That will take you to the `eslint` repo, i.e. [this one](https://github.com/eslint/eslint)
5. On the Github page click the *"Branch"* button - which appears above the list of source code files, and looks like this:

   [image: Github branch button]
6. In the *pop-up* panel that subsequently appears click the *"Tags"* button, then locate and click the version tag from the list that you want to discover it's dependencies. *(Note: These tag names will typically correspond to the version released/published to npm)*

   This will then load the source code files in the browser for that particular release/version.
7. Locate the *package.json* file from the list of files and click it. This will load the contents of  *package.json* in the browser, upon which you can read it and ascertain its dependencies.

---

#### Visualizing the dependency tree

I sometimes utilize this online tool https://npm.anvaka.com which can help you to visualize the complete dependency tree/graph for a given package - however it's for the latest version of a package only.

[Here](https://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/eslint) is the complete dependency tree/graph (many levels deep) for the latest version of eslint.

Comment: All the `npm view` command (or it's alias `npm show`) work successfully with [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) too. For instance: `npm show @babel/core@7.4.0 dependencies` and also as per point 3; `npm show @babel/core@7.4.0 dependencies.@babel/helpers`

Comment: I keep coming back to this page. Great answer.

Comment: @RobC quick question: is it that using some-package@somePreviousVersion doesn't work either? I mean, does npm registry return the proper dependency versions of previous package versions? I ask this because it seems I'm experiencing this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75014308/544947