# Rolling back to previous version of npm package doesn't work?

Tags: typescript, npm, github-actions, npx, commitlint

(This question revolves more around npm and how dependencies and versions work in this ecosystem; `commitlint` is just an example of the issue at hand, but I imagine it could happen with any npm package.)

I was using `commitlint` npm package happily for the past few months to lint my commit messages. I even developed some commitlint plugins in TypeScript to enhance it with our repo's policies.

Now comes version 17.4.0 of commitlint: apparently [they raised the version of their TypeScript dependency](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/commit/bf86c7dddc34c70d552decc040b30049a002d6a2), so my plugins don't compile anymore (some issue with `any` types that I will look into later).

So then I decide to rollback to commitlint v17.3.0 in my CI recipe, as a temporary workaround until I can look into fixing our plugins, via:

```
npm install @commitlint/config-conventional@17.3.0
```

But, it doesn't work! I keep getting the TypeScript compiler error. Oh, then I try with `-g`:

```
npm install -g @commitlint/config-conventional@17.3.0
```

Same thing, I keep getting the error. Oh, maybe `-g` requires sudo?

```
sudo npm install -g @commitlint/config-conventional@17.3.0
```

No! Still same error. What the hell might be going on here? Then I look at the CI log and I notice this in the `npx` call:

```
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: commitlint@17.4.0
```

Aha! So, somehow, npx is not **seeing** the recently installed commitlint version that the previous `npm install` step performed. How is this possible? Any ideas?

Well, then I thought, let's do a workaround, removing the npm install step and just specifying the version in the npx call:

```
npx commitlint@17.3.0 --from HEAD~1 --to HEAD --verbose
```

...and guess what? It doesn't work either! This is the log:

```
Run npx commitlint@17.3.0 --from HEAD~1 --to HEAD --verbose
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: commitlint@17.3.0
/home/runner/.npm/_npx/f46b942c1a6d2ab7/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
...
```

How is this possible? Is it that previous versions of npm packages still point to the dependencies of the latest version? Wouldn't this be an npm/npx bug?

**UPDATE:** Interesting discovery so far: `commitlint` package seems to depend on package [commitlint/types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@commitlint/types?activeTab=versions), which doesn't seem to have a 17.3.0 version.

Comment: Did you try to install the old version using npm install xyz—force? Iirc npm checks to see if a newer version already exists, and if so uses that from the local node_modules folder.

Comment: but there is no node_modules folder, it would be created by `npm install` in CI

Comment: So are you trying to get things working in a CI system (and if so, which one?). From the commands it looked like you were doing this locally. Does it work as explicated locally?

Comment: actually I just tested locally and I have the same problem; --force didn't help :'(

Comment: calling `node_modules/commit-lint/cli.js` --version returns 17.3.0 so it did install the previous version; but somehow the TypeScript compiler downloaded is the one from the new version